# Inference on Treatment Effects after Selection among High-Dimensional Controls

Tags: econometrics, dimensionality-reduction, instrumental-variables

I am reading the work by Belloni et al (2014), see the name in the title (weblink [here](http://restud.oxfordjournals.org/content/81/2/608.full.pdf+html)). What I understand is that they assume that the outcome can be well approximated by a small/sparse set of controls but the researcher does not know which those controls are from a high dimensional set of possible controls. They outline well the usual OLS case with one treatment variable using LASSO. You would first regress the outcome on all possible controls, their squares, and interactions, and then select significant predictors using LASSO. Next, regress the treatment variable on those controls and do the selection again. Finally, regress the outcome on the treatment and the union of the selected controls in the previous two steps.

But how would their procedure work with instrumental variables (IV)? I think they discuss this in the latter part of the paper but this part is much harder so I don't follow well.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: Belloni, A., Chernozhukov, V., and Christian Hansen (2014) "Inference on Treatment Effects after Selection among High-Dimensional Controls", Review of Economic Studies, Vol. 81, No. 2, pp. 608-650

Comment: Please paste in whatever context is necessary to understand & answer your question.
We want this thread to remain valuable even if the link goes dead. also, please add a full citation for the paper.